# How can I check the topic of all channels in a guild?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to check the channel topic using the code shown below but it keeps giving me a TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined I'd love to have someone help me out. Thanks!

I've tried changing the function and researching the include method but I can't find anything related to discord.js

````cs
const guild = message.guild;
      const channel = message.guild.channels;
      function checking(channel) {
          channel.topic.includes(message.author.id)
      }
      const channelOpen = guild.channels.some(checking)
      if(channelOpen === true) return message.channel.send("You already have a ticket open!")```

Check the channel topic for the author of the message's ID and if it finds their ID in a topic, return with a message.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
  var count = 0
  message.guild.channels.forEach(i => {
    if(count == 1) return; //If ID is already found.
    if(i.type == 'voice') return; //If it's voice channel, return.
    if(i.topic == message.author.id){ count++; return message.reply('You already have a ticket open!') }
    //If ID is already found, increase the number to stop code from executing and message author about ticket.
  });
```

What I used:
[forEach loop](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)

[if statements](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp)

channel properties: [type](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel?scrollTo=type), [topic](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=topic)

[Increment](https://codeburst.io/javascript-increment-and-decrement-8c223858d5ed) on **count**, you can **ONLY** change **var** and **let** variables.

More on variables: [here](https://tylermcginnis.com/var-let-const/).

If I helped you, please mark this as answer so I can get higher reputation. Thanks <3

Answer (score 0):

`message.guild.channels` does not have a `topic` property, which is why you are getting a TypeError. You could instead use the `find()` method, like so:

```
const checking = message.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.topic === message.author.id) || null
if (checking) return message.channel.send("You already have a ticket open!")
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

So there is not enough info more to to answer this completely, but I can tell you this. It's telling you that you're trying to access a property on an undefined object.  The guild arr doesn't have a property (message.author.id)  at all, which means it's undefined. Since that doesn't exist, there's no way for it to have an includes property available of any type.

What you need is to access an object in the array, not the array itself. Something like guild[0].something.something would refer to an instantiated object. This only works on an Array. If you would like to do this on an object you need to use object1.hasOwnProperty('*Item to check for *')
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

```
    const object1 = new Object();
object1.property1 = 42;

console.log(object1.hasOwnProperty('property1'));
// expected output: true

console.log(object1.hasOwnProperty('toString'));
// expected output: false

console.log(object1.hasOwnProperty('hasOwnProperty'));





  const channel = message.guild.channels; 
   // You should log the guild object* to see Data. Please show data when 
   //posting question. For example message[0].guild.channel ? 

  function checking(channel) {

      channel.topic.includes(message.author.id)
      // I would write it like 
     // return channel.topic.hasOwnProperty(message.author.id)
  }
   //Checking is declared but never called ? 

  const channelOpen = guild.channels.some(checking)
   //you did not post the guild object or arr, so not sure why you are calling 
   //some with the checking function ? 
   //I think what your trying to do is channelOpen = checking(channel) ? 
  if(channelOpen) {
  // you dont need == true 

   return message.channel.send("You already have a ticket open!")
    }
```